# Finding a system of linear equations which result is a given matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say I have three matrices forming a true equation as follows:

$$
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 1\\
    -2 & 2 & 6\\
    1 & 1 & 1\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\times
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -2\\
    1\\
    -1\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\
=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    -2\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

And I have to find a system of three linear equations such that the following matrice (as seen in the above equation) is the solution (using the other two equations somehow):

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -2\\
    1\\
    -1\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Also important to note that it needs to have three equations and three variables.

I have tried playing around with the other two equations and experimenting with WolframAlpha to find a system of linear equations with three variables and three equations for the solution, but I'm not being very successful.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that given a solution $x$, you look for another matrix $M$ and a right-hand side $b$ such that $Mx=b$? Or is $b$ also given?

Comment: How about solving $x_1=-2, x_2=1, x_3 = -1$?

Comment: @PavelJiranek That's what I'm looking for, perhaps in the form of "ax + by + cz = k, dx + ey + fz = l, gx + hy + iz = n;".

Comment: @copper.hat well, theoretically I _can_ do that, but it's a bit silly and way too simple. I didn't mention it but this is an assignment, I'm guessing I have to work a bit harder than that, but good idea :)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Are you asking for a different matrix and right hand side so that the given vector is the unique solution? Pick any invertible $A$, compute $b=A (2,1,-1)^T$ and solve $Ax=b$.

Comment: I'm supposed to use in some way the first equation I posted right in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Given $x$ and looking for $M$ such that $Mx=b$ where

1) $b$ is arbitrary: Pick any $M$ and put $b=Mx$

2) $b$ is given: take $M=bx^{\dagger}+Z(I-xx^{\dagger})$, where $x^{\dagger}=x^T/(x^Tx)$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of the vector $x$ and $Z$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

X+3y+z=0
Did u see what I did?
Its visual gymnastics!
This question can be 'solved' in less than 10 secs!
Cheers!
Take it from here!

Comment: I need 3 equations.